# Does "e.namedValues('')" pull in empty results in an array or only the answered fields?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

We are working to create a script that will take the information from a Google Form.

We have a Form that has four unique, multiple choice questions, containing the same title and response options:

Title = Incident Type
Reponse = Accidental or Stolen

But are separated by previous answer paths (meaning 3 of them will be unanswered on every form submission). When this form is written to a sheet the ones that were not answered are empty leaving the one that was with the value we are trying to obtain.

Here's a link to our Google Form for reference. The question that ia asked is "Incident Type", it is asked to the person once, in the answer path, but the form has it listed 4 times.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSffaHkwQdfOE1e52Lkq1Eob1SyIb4O3po852NpZmVPCg3CNxA/viewform?usp=sf_link

The information is coming from a Googel Form, but the script is running on a Google Sheet, which is exporting to a Google Doc.

**The question we have: Does e.namedValues['question title'] pull in the empty results in an array or only the answered question?**

Here is an example of our code:

```
function createReport(e) {
   /*ADD VARIABLES HERE*/

  var incidentNumber = e.values[9];
  var incidentType = e.namedValues['Incident Type'];

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXX');
  var reportdoc = DriveApp.getFileById('XXX').makeCopy('Device Damage/Loss Report for ' + studentName, folder);

    //Load and Open document for editing
  var editReport = DocumentApp.openById(reportdoc.getId())
  var tables = editReport.getBody().getTables();

  /*EDIT TABLES BEYOND HERE*/

  **//Incident Cost for Type Table Modification
  if (incidentType == 'Accidental Damage') {
      if (incidentNumber == '1st Incident') {
        tables[4].getCell(1, 0).clear();
        tables[4].getCell(1, 0).appendListItem('').setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.SQUARE_BULLET);
      }
      else if (incidentNumber == '2nd Incident') {
        tables[4].getCell(2, 0).clear();
        tables[4].getCell(2, 0).appendListItem('').setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.SQUARE_BULLET);
      }
      else if (incidentNumber == '3rd Incident') {
        tables[4].getCell(3, 0).clear();
        tables[4].getCell(3, 0).appendListItem('').setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.SQUARE_BULLET);
      }
    else if (incidentNumber == 'Not Covered') {
      return;    
    }
  } else if (incidentType == 'Stolen') {
      if (incidentNumber == '1st Incident') {
        tables[4].getCell(1, 2).clear();
        tables[4].getCell(1, 2).appendListItem('1st Incident: $25').setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.SQUARE_BULLET);
      }
      else if (incidentNumber == '2nd Incident') {
        tables[4].getCell(2, 2).clear();
        tables[4].getCell(2, 2).appendListItem('').setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.SQUARE_BULLET);
      }
      else if (incidentNumber == '3rd Incident') {
        tables[4].getCell(3, 2).clear();
        tables[4].getCell(3, 2).appendListItem('').setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.SQUARE_BULLET);
      }
    else if (incidentNumber == 'Not Covered') {
        return;
    } 
  } else {
      return;
  }**
```

Comment: The object will have an empty array for the question that is unanswered.  The object will have an element with the question title.  You can see all the content of that event object with a Logger.log() statement:  `Logger.log(e.namedValues)`  Submit the Form, and then VIEW the LOGS.  The object will not be displayed in JSON format, but you will see the content.